# Can't change color in material timepicker in keyboard mode

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the background color of the inactive input field in the material time picker's keyboard mode, the circled grey part in the [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGyQN.png). I can't find a way to change it however.

The timepicker's code is as follows:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
                .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
                //.setTheme(R.style.Timepicker_theme)
                .setInputMode(MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
                .build();
        materialTimePicker.show(fragmentManager, "a");
```

And this is the primary theme I'm using:

```
    <style name="Theme.app" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/dark_blue_primary</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue_primary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/blue_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/yellow_primary</item>
        <!-- Text color. -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dark_blue_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/dark_blue_primary</item>
    </style>
```

I've tried changing the theme using `.setTheme(R.style.Timepicker_theme)`, which crashes unless the style inherits `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker`. Using this style I can change the elements in the clock mode, but not the keyboard mode.

I might be missing something due to not being very experienced with android development, but I couldn't find anything that worked after several hours of googling. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead setting the main theme I suggest you to use seprate theme. Like this:

theme.xml(light and night) according change color

```
<!--Theme for TimePicker-->
<style name="Custom_MaterialTimePicker_Theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <!--This is our main theme color of picker-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appPrimaryColor</item>
    <!--The color of the text inside the selected circle of the hours and minutes hands.-->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#FFF5F5F5</item>
    <!--This is the background color of the dialog.-->
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/dialogBackgroundColor</item>
    <!--This sets the background color of the clock circle (which was gray) and the text color of the unselected hours and minutes.-->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="materialTimePickerTitleStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title</item>
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/borderlessButtonStyle</item>
    <!--Sets the text color even in keyboard mode-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/MaterialTimePickerButtonOutlinedStyle</item>
</style>
<!--    For TimePicker Title Text-->
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TimePicker.Title" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <!-- Add any other title-related attributes here -->
</style>
<!--    For TimePicker Button Text-->
<style name="borderlessButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="MaterialTimePickerButtonOutlinedStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/selector_time_picker_am_pm_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_time_picker_am_pm_button_text</item>
</style>
```

Your Kotlin code should be:

```
materialTimePickerBuilder.setTheme(R.style.Custom_MaterialTimePicker_Theme)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time input in Time Picker uses chip style. Using theme overlays, you can set your color for chip style in Time Picker.

First, override the `materialTimePickerTheme` with your overlay. In that overlay, you can set `chipStyle` for the time input. You can set your desired color using the `chipBackgroundColor` attribute in this style.

```xml
<style name="Theme.App" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="materialTimePickerTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TimePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/Widget.App.TimePicker.Display</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.TimePicker.Display" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Display">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>
```

If you want to remove the background, you can set the chip background color to `?colorSurface`. But that will also remove its border, so add a stroke.

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.TimePicker.Display" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.Display">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">?colorSurface</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">?colorOnSurface</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
</style>
```